# How we can process payment using balancedpayments?

Tags: php, balanced-payments

When using the following code, I get an error:

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
Settings::$api_key = $API_KEY_SECRET;
$marketplace = Marketplace::mine();
if ($page == '/')
{
  // do nothing
} 
elseif ($page == '/buyer') {
if (isset($_POST['uri']) and isset($_POST['email_address'])) {
    // create in balanced
    $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
    $card_uri = $_POST['uri'];
    try {
        echo create_buyer($email_address, $card_uri)->uri;
        return;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return;
    }
}
}

function create_buyer($email_address, $card_uri) {
$marketplace = Marketplace::mine();
try {
    # new buyer
    $buyer = $marketplace->createBuyer(
        $email_address,
        $card_uri);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->category_code == 'duplicate-email-address') {
        # oops, account for $email_address already exists so just add the card
        $buyer = $marketplace
            ->accounts
            ->query()
            ->filter(Account::$f->email_address->eq($email_address))
            ->one();
        $buyer->addCard($card_uri);
    }
    else {
        throw $e;
    }     
}
return $buyer;
 }
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'NoResultFound' in     /var/www/html/site/balancepayment/Balanced/Core/Query.php:134 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/site/balancepayment/Balanced/Marketplace.php(48): Query->one() #1 /var/www/html/site/balancepayment/index.php(16): Marketplace::mine() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/site/balancepayment/Balanced/Core/Query.php on line 134

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a marketplace like in the first step of the tutorial?

https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/php#quickstart

```
Balanced\Settings::$api_key = $key->secret;
$marketplace = new Balanced\Marketplace();
$marketplace->save();
```

Comment: yes.. i have done that already..let me give you my code to that section

Comment: Debashish - Have you looked at the examples.php file in the library - https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/example/example.php - See lines 43 onwards for how to  create payments.

Answer (score 0):

OK so right at the top of the code example there is the comment

```
/**
 * Represents a marketplace.
 * 
 * To get started you create an api key and then create a marketplace:
 *
```

However, for some reason my dev does not apear to be following the directions in sequence.

BalancedPayments, 
I am not much of a coder, can you confirm my dev is not properly following directions in the proper sequence here. Looks like they are trying to skip the first 2 steps....

```
<?php


/**
 * Represents a marketplace.
 * 
 * To get started you create an api key and then create a marketplace:
 *   
 * <code>
 * $api_key = new \Balanced\APIKey();
 * $api_key->save();
 * $secret = $api_key->secret  // better save this somewhere
 * print $secret;
 * \Balanced\Settings::$api_key = $secret;
 * 
 * $marketplace = new \Balanced\Marketplace();
 * $marketplace->save();
 * var_dump($marketplace); 
 * </code>
 * 
 * Each api key is uniquely assocaited with an api key so once you've created a
 * marketplace:
 * 
 * <code>
 * \Balanced\Settings::$api_key = $secret;
 * $marketplace = \Balanced\Marketplace::mine();  // this is the marketplace associated with $secret  
 * </code>
 */
class Marketplace extends Resource
{
    protected static $_uri_spec = null;

    public static function init()
    {
        self::$_uri_spec = new URISpec('marketplaces', 'id', '/v1');
        self::$_registry->add(get_called_class());
    }

    /**
     * Get the marketplace associated with the currently configured
     * \Balanced\Settings::$api_key. 
     *
     * @throws \Balanced\Exceptions\NoResult
     * @return \Balanced\Marketplace
     */
    public static function mine()
    {
        return self::query()->one();
    }

    /**
     * Create a card. These can later be associated with an account using
     * \Balanced\Account->addCard or \Balanced\Marketplace->createBuyer. 
     * 
     * @param string street_address Street address. Use null if there is no address for the card.
     * @param string city City. Use null if there is no address for the card.
     * @param string postal_code Postal code. Use null if there is no address for the card.
     * @param string name Name as it appears on the card.
     * @param string card_number Card number.
     * @param string security_code Card security code. Use null if it is no available.
     * @param int expiration_month Expiration month.
     * @param int expiration_year Expiration year.
     * 
     * @return \Balanced\Card
     */
    public function createCard(
        $street_address,
        $city,
        $region,
        $postal_code,
        $name,
        $card_number,
        $security_code,
        $expiration_month,
        $expiration_year)
    {
        if ($region != null && strlen($region) > 0) {
            trigger_error("The region parameter will be deprecated in the next minor version of balanced-php", E_USER_NOTICE);
        }

        return $this->cards->create(array(
            'street_address' => $street_address,
            'city' => $city,
            'region' => $region,
            'postal_code' => $postal_code,
            'name' => $name,
            'card_number' => $card_number,
            'security_code' => $security_code,
            'expiration_month' => $expiration_month,
            'expiration_year' => $expiration_year
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Create a bank account. These can later be associated with an account
     * using \Balanced\Account->addBankAccount.
     * 
     * @param string name Name of the account holder.
     * @param string account_number Account number.
     * @param string bank_code Bank code or routing number.
     * 
     * @return \Balanced\BankAccount
     */
    public function createBankAccount(
        $name,
        $account_number,
        $bank_code
        )
    {
        return $this->bank_accounts->create(array(
            'name' => $name,
            'account_number' => $account_number,
            'bank_code' => $bank_code,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Create a role-less account. You can later turn this into a buyer by
     * adding a funding source (e.g a card) or a merchant using
     * \Balanced\Account->promoteToMerchant.
     *
     * @param string email_address Email address. There can only be one account with this email address.
     * @param array[string]string meta Optional metadata to associate with the account.
     *
     * @return \Balanced\Account
     */
    public function createAccount($email_address, $meta = null)
    {
        return $this->accounts->create(array(
            'email_address' => $email_address,
            'meta' => $meta,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Create a buyer account.
     * 
     * @param string email_address Email address. There can only be one account with this email address.
     * @param string card_uri URI referencing a card to associate with the account.
     * @param array[string]string meta Optional metadata to associate with the account.
     *
     * @return \Balanced\Account
     */
    public function createBuyer($email_address, $card_uri, $meta = null)
    {
        return $this->accounts->create(array(
            'email_address' => $email_address,
            'card_uri' => $card_uri,
            'meta' => $meta,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * Create a merchant account.
     * 
     * Unlike buyers the identity of a merchant must be established before
     * the account can function as a merchant (i.e. be credited). A merchant
     * can be either a person or a business. Either way that information is
     * represented as an associative array and passed as the merchant parameter
     * when creating the merchant account.
     * 
     * For a person the array looks like this:
     * 
     * <code>
     * array(
     *     'type' => 'person',
     *     'name' => 'William James',
     *     'tax_id' => '393-48-3992',
     *     'street_address' => '167 West 74th Street',
     *     'postal_code' => '10023',
     *     'dob' => '1842-01-01',
     *     'phone_number' => '+16505551234',
     *     'country_code' => 'USA'
     *     )
     * </code>
     * 
     * For a business the array looks like this:
     * 
     * <code>
     * array(
     *     'type' => 'business',
     *     'name' => 'Levain Bakery',
     *     'tax_id' => '253912384',
     *     'street_address' => '167 West 74th Street',
     *     'postal_code' => '10023',
     *     'phone_number' => '+16505551234',
     *     'country_code' => 'USA',
     *     'person' => array(
     *         'name' => 'William James',
     *         'tax_id' => '393483992',
     *         'street_address' => '167 West 74th Street',
     *         'postal_code' => '10023',
     *         'dob' => '1842-01-01',
     *         'phone_number' => '+16505551234',
     *         'country_code' => 'USA',
     *         )
     *     )
     * </code>
     * 
     * In some cases the identity of the merchant, person or business, cannot
     * be verified in which case a \Balanced\Exceptions\HTTPError is thrown:
     * 
     * <code>
     * $identity = array(
     *     'type' => 'business',
     *     'name' => 'Levain Bakery',
     *     'tax_id' => '253912384',
     *     'street_address' => '167 West 74th Street',
     *     'postal_code' => '10023',
     *     'phone_number' => '+16505551234',
     *     'country_code' => 'USA',
     *     'person' => array(
     *         'name' => 'William James',
     *         'tax_id' => '393483992',
     *         'street_address' => '167 West 74th Street',
     *         'postal_code' => '10023',
     *         'dob' => '1842-01-01',
     *         'phone_number' => '+16505551234',
     *         'country_code' => 'USA',
     *         ),
     *     );
     *     
     *  try {
     *      $merchant = \Balanced\Marketplace::mine()->createMerchant(
     *          'merchant@example.com',
     *          $identity,
     *          );
     *  catch (\Balanced\Exceptions\HTTPError $e) {
     *      if ($e->code != 300) {
     *          throw $e;   
     *      }
     *      print e->response->header['Location'] // this is where merchant must signup
     *  }
     * </code>
     * 
     * Once the merchant has completed signup you can use the resulting URI to
     * create an account for them on your marketplace:
     * 
     * <code>
     * $merchant = self::$marketplace->createMerchant(
     *     'merchant@example.com',
     *     null,
     *     null,
     *     $merchant_uri
     *     );
     * </coe>
     * 
     * @param string email_address Email address. There can only be one account with this email address.
     * @param array[string]mixed merchant Associative array describing the merchants identity.
     * @param string $bank_account_uri Optional URI referencing a bank account to associate with this account.
     * @param string $merchant_uri URI of a merchant created via the redirection sign-up flow.
     * @param string $name Optional name of the merchant.
     * @param array[string]string meta Optional metadata to associate with the account.
     * 
     * @return \Balanced\Account
     */
    public function createMerchant(
        $email_address,
        $merchant = null,
        $bank_account_uri = null,
        $merchant_uri = null,
        $name = null,
        $meta = null
        )
    {
        return $this->accounts->create(array(
            'email_address' => $email_address,
            'merchant' => $merchant,
            'merchant_uri' => $merchant_uri,
            'bank_account_uri' => $bank_account_uri,
            'name' => $name,
            'meta' => $meta,
            ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the custom library for balanced payments which is availble on github
https://github.com/yousafsyed/balancedpayments

Here is the example of usage

```
 require ("balancedpayments.php");

$config = array(
"apikey"              => "ak-test-23923840140fisdfjsodfjd9fjks22sdww", // set your api    key secret
"payment_description" => " Charging the card", // set the payment description
"statement_appear_as" => "Example Company"// set the statement

);


Balancedpayments::config($config); // pass the config array


/**
 * Create customer example
 * */
$userdata = array(
"name"          => "yousaf",
"email"         => "mmesunny@gmail.com",
"adddres"       => "NY street 1",
"meta[user_id]" => "123"
);
Balancedpayments::create_user($userdata);
```

**For More Usage Example See the example on github**
https://github.com/yousafsyed/balancedpayments#usage